# GCM push notification are not recived by all android clients

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have an android application as client and ASP.Net + ADO.Net hosted on GoDaddy server.

Altough a GCM message is sent successfully not all clients get the notification . i have three clients : mini galaxi , nexus 7 (android 4.2.1) nexus 4 (android 4.2.2). i am sending push notification via GCM to all clients. meesages are sent at different time. the mini galaxi and nexus 7 recive about 95% of the notifications but the nexus 4 get about 10%.

One more interesting info : when the android application @ the nexux 4 is closed and reopen after reciving notification then the precentage of reciving notification rise significantly.

What can possibly be the reason ?

What to do to solve this ?

Nathan

Comment: this is a very good tutorial for GCM, i have used it & it's working fine : http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Comment: Thank You. My problem is not that i dont get push notification , the problem mostly is that on particular device it is not working as it expected. so i do not assume there is a problem with the code otherwise it would not work for any device.